# Custom Composite Control not rendering correctly for only 0.5-1 sec after being added back into a VGROUP

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, adobe, custom-controls

I am moving away from **MXML** and have built a custom component control within **ActionScript**.

I have the control displaying correctly. The problem comes after I remove it from the display list and add it back in again with the .addElement(control) method.

Here is the code that adds it back in again.

```
private function displayParameters(parameters:ArrayCollection):void{

   for(var index:int = 0; index<parameters.length; index++){

      if(parameters[index] is ReportControl){

          var control:ReportControl = parameters[index] as ReportControl;
          control.percentWidth = 100;
          vgParameters.addElement(control);
      }
   }
}
```

`ReportControl` is the base class for `comboBoxMultiSelect` which is shown below. There is nothing graphically special about `ReportControl`, it only serves as a programmatic interface for its concrete implementations (polymorphic).

```
public class comboBoxMultiSelect extends ReportControl{

    [Embed("../Assets/Icons/plus-16.png")]
    private var plusIcon:Class;
    [Embed("../Assets/Icons/minus-16.png")]
    private var minusIcon:Class;

    private var expanded:Boolean = false;
    private var buttonIconChanged:Boolean = false;

    private var _drp:ComboBox;
    private var _btnMultiple:Button;
    private var _horizontalGroup:HGroup;
    private var _multiSelector:ReportGridSelector;

    private var _multiSelection:Boolean = true;
    private var bMultiSelectionChanged:Boolean = false;        

    public function ToggleExpanded():void{
        expanded = !_expanded;
        buttonIconChanged = true;

        invalidateSize();
        invalidateProperties();
        invalidateDisplayList();
    }

    public function comboBoxMultiSelect(){
        super();
    }

    override protected function createChildren():void{

        super.createChildren();            

        if(!_horizontalGroup){
            _horizontalGroup = new HGroup();
            _horizontalGroup.gap = 0;
            _horizontalGroup.percentWidth = 100;
            _horizontalGroup.height = ReportControl.SIZE_DEFAULT_HEIGHT;
             addChild(_horizontalGroup);
        }

        if(!_drp){
            _drp = new ComboBox();
            _drp.text = GuiText;
            _drp.percentWidth = 100;
            _drp.height = ReportControl.SIZE_DEFAULT_HEIGHT; 
            _horizontalGroup.addElement(_drp);
        }

        if(!_btnMultiple && _multiSelection){
            _btnMultiple = new Button;
            _btnMultiple.setStyle("icon", plusIcon);
            _btnMultiple.width = 20;
            _btnMultiple.height = ReportControl.SIZE_DEFAULT_HEIGHT;
            _btnMultiple.visible = true;
            _btnMultiple.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,
                         function(event:MouseEvent):void{
                                 ToggleExpanded();   
                         });
            _horizontalGroup.addElement(_btnMultiple);
        }
    }

    override protected function commitProperties():void{
        super.commitProperties();

        if(buttonIconChanged){

            if(_expanded==true){
                _btnMultiple.setStyle("icon", minusIcon);
            }
            else{
                _btnMultiple.setStyle("icon", plusIcon);
            }
            buttonIconChanged = false;
        }

    }

    override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number,
                                         unscaledHeight:Number):void{

        super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

        _horizontalGroup.width = unscaledWidth;
        _horizontalGroup.height = unscaledHeight;
    }

    override protected function measure():void{

        super.measure();
        measuredMinWidth = measuredWidth = ReportControl.SIZE_DEFAULT_WIDTH;

        //minimum size      //default size
        if(_expanded==true)
            measuredMinHeight= measuredHeight = 200;            
        else
            measuredMinHeight= measuredHeight = 
                               ReportControl.SIZE_DEFAULT_HEIGHT;
    }
}
```

When I add the control back in using `vgParameters.addElement(control)`, the `comboBoxMultiSelect` is not rendering properly. The `plusIcon` inside the button `_btnMultiple` is not postioned correctly at first, but then quickly corrects itself about 0.5-1 secs later.

I pretty sure the problem lies within comboBoxMultiSelect, just not sure how to force the icon to stay in the same place.

This is highly annoying after all my hard work, anyone have ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Thanks :)

**UPDATE -----> Here is the ReportControl code**

```
[Event (name= "controlChanged", type="Reporting.ReportControls.ReportControlEvent")]
[Event (name= "controlIsNowValid", type="Reporting.ReportControls.ReportControlEvent")]
public class ReportControl extends UIComponent
{
    private var _guiText:String;
    private var _amfPHPArgumentName:String;
    private var _reportResult:ReportResult;
    private var _sequence:int;
    private var _reportId:int;
    private var _controlConfiguration:ReportParameterVO;
    private var _isValid:Boolean = false;
    internal var _selection:Object;

    /**
     * SIZE_DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 22
     */
    internal static const SIZE_DEFAULT_HEIGHT:int = 22;

    /**
     * SIZE_DEFAULT_WIDTH = 150
     */
    internal static const SIZE_DEFAULT_WIDTH:int = 150;

    public function get ControlConfiguration():ReportParameterVO{
        return _controlConfiguration;
    }

    public function set ControlConfiguration(value:ReportParameterVO):void{

        _controlConfiguration = value;            
        _guiText = (value ? value.GuiText:"");
        _amfPHPArgumentName = (value ? value.AMFPHP_ArgumentName: "");
        _sequence = (value ? value.Sequence : null);
        _reportId = (value ? value.ReportId : null);            
    }

    public function get IsValid():Boolean{
        return _isValid;
    }

    public function get ReportID():int{
        return _reportId;
    }

    public function get Sequence():int{
        return _sequence;
    }

    public function get ControlRepResult():ReportResult{
        return _reportResult;
    }
    public function set ControlRepResult(value:ReportResult):void{
        _reportResult = value;
    }

    internal function set Selection(value:Object):void{
        _selection = value;
    }

    internal function get Selection():Object{
        return _selection;
    }

    public function get ParameterSelection():Object{
        return _selection;
    }

    public function get GuiText():String{
        return _guiText;
    }

    public function get AmfPHPArgumentName():String{
        return _amfPHPArgumentName;
    }

    public function ReportControl(){
        //TODO: implement function
        super();
    }

    public function dispatchControlChanged():void{
        this.dispatchEvent(new ReportControlEvent(ReportControlEvent.CONTROL_CHANGED, this, true));
    }
    public function dispatchControlIsNowValid():void{
        this.dispatchEvent(new ReportControlEvent(ReportControlEvent.CONTROL_IS_NOW_VALID, this, true));
    }

    public function addSelfToValueObject(valueObject:Object):Object{
        valueObject[AmfPHPArgumentName] = _selection;
        return valueObject;
    }

}
```

Comment: May I ask why you are "slowly moving away from MXML"? It probably took you hours to create this simple composite class, which would have taken you minutes if you wrote it in MXML and let the framework take care of the difficulties for you. Where is the gain in that? If you want to separate layout (mxml) from behaviour (as), I can show you how to do that if you wish, though it wouldn't really be an answer to your question.

Comment: We needed some form of abstraction for 'X' number of control types we might need in the future. And I felt that doing it with MXML (although certainly would have been faster) would have taken some degree of control away. Plus we're learning flex so what better way than to dive into the Component Life Cycle

Comment: Learning the component life cycle is one thing, abstraction is another. I don't exactly understand what you mean by abstraction in this context, but I have a feeling you should take a look at the Spark skinning architecture, which lets you write one host component that can take many forms (as skins). Here's an old answer of mine that shows a very simple example of this concept: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930740/what-is-the-hostcomponent/9931286#9931286. (Unfortunately, it's so simple that it doesn't have any behaviour.) Most Spark components are constructed with this concept.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear, what I mean by abstraction is SuperClass-->SubClass relationship. In this case ReportControl-->comboBoxMultiSelect. The visual representation of each control would standardized, (same column, font size etc...). But the functionality of each control could be drastically different. Essentially what we are building is an ad-hoc reporting engine, where each report has its own "Parameter Configuration". The class in this question will eventually be used as a selector for a report.

Comment: I've seen your base class now. This is a perfect candidate for what I've explained in my previous comment. Have your ReportControl extend SkinnableComponent instead of UIComponent, separate the visual representation of ComboBoxMultiSelect into an mxml-based skin class, and define the properties and behaviour of the component in the as-based host component which extends ReportControl. It'll take away the pain of having to manage the layout manually and add even more abstraction.

Comment: I think I understand what your saying. Very much like how HTML+CSS websites separate out the structure and presentation. In this context the modularity would come from being able to change the visual control layout without having to modify underlying actionScript

Comment: Spot on! Except for this difference: the skins will also allow you to programmatically change the visual representation (e.g. transition effects) which you can't do with CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to give you an example of what I mean with the Spark skinning architecture we've discussed in the comments above. It's not directly an answer to your question, but I thought you might find it interesting. I will have to make it somewhat simpler than your component for brevity's sake and because you seem to have stripped out some of the code for your question so I can't know exactly what it's supposed to do.

This will be a component that will let you toggle between a normal and an expanded state through the click of a Button. First we'll create the skin class. Normally you'd create the host component first, but it'll be easier to explain this way.

```
<!-- my.skins.ComboBoxMultiSelectSkin -->
<s:Skin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        height.normal="25" height.expanded="200">

    <fx:Metadata>
        [HostComponent("my.components.ComboBoxMultiSelect")]
    </fx:Metadata>

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="normal" />
        <s:State name="expanded" />
    </s:states>

    <s:layout>
        <s:HorizontalLayout gap="0" />
    </s:layout>

    <s:ComboBox id="comboBox" width="100%" />
    <s:Button id="toggleButton" width="20"
              icon.normal="@Embed('../Assets/Icons/plus-16.png')"
              icon.expanded="@Embed('../Assets/Icons/minus-16.png')"/>

</s:Skin>
```

Thus we've set up completely how your component will look and how it will lay out. Do you feel your headaches dissipating? I for one find this quite elegant. We have the two states and the height of the component will adjust to the currently selected state as will the icon of the Button. How and when the state is toggled is component behaviour and will be defined in the host component.

Now let's create that host component in plain ActionScript. For this we'll extend SkinnableComponent (note that it could also extend your ReportControl if that would extend SkinnableComponent instead of UIComponent).

```
[SkinState("normal")]
[SkinState("expanded")]
public class ComboBoxMultiSelect extends SkinnableComponent {

    [SkinPart(required="true")]
    public var toggleButton:IEventDispatcher;

    [SkinPart(required="true")]
    public var comboBox:ComboBox;

    private var expanded:Boolean;

    override protected function partAdded(partName:String, instance:Object):void {
        super.partAdded(partName, instance);

        switch (instance) {
            case toggleButton:  
                toggleButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleToggleButtonClick); 
                break;
            case comboBox:
                comboBox.addEventListener(IndexChangeEvent.CHANGE, handleComboSelection);
                break;
        }
    }

    private function handleToggleButtonClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
        toggleExpanded();
    }

    private function handleComboSelection(event:IndexChangeEvent):void {
        //handle comboBox selection
    }

    protected function toggleExpanded():void {
        expanded = !expanded;
        invalidateSkinState();
    }

    override protected function getCurrentSkinState():String {
        return expanded ? "expanded" : "normal";
    }
}
```

Allright, there's a lot more going on here.

- First look at the `SkinState` metadata declarations: when a skin class is assigned to the component, the compiler will check whether that skin has the required states implemented.
- Then the `SkinPart` declarations: the name of the property on the host component must exactly match the id of the tag in the skin class. As `required` is set to `true` the compiler will check whether these components do really exist in the skin. If you want optional skin parts, you set it to `false`.
- Note that the type of `toggleButton` is `IEventDispatcher`: from the host component's point of view, all `toggleButton` has to do, is dispatching CLICK events. This means that we could now create a skin with `<s:Image id="toggleButton" source="..." />` and the whole thing would keep working the same way. See how powerful this is?
- Because the skinpart properties are not assigned immediately, we override the `partAdded()` method which will be executed whenever a component becomes available. In most cases this is the place where you hook up your event listeners.
- In the `toggleExpanded()` method, we toggle the boolean just like the component in your question, however we only invalidate the skin state. This will cause the skin to call the `getCurrentSkinState()` method and update its state to whatever value is returned.

Et voilà! You have a working component with the behaviour nicely separated into an actionscript class and you didn't have to worry about the layout intricacies. And if you ever wish to create a component with the same behaviour, but it should expand horizontally instead of vertically: just create a new skin that adjusts the `width` instead of the `height` and assign that to the same host component.

Oh wait! I nearly forgot to tell you how to assign the skin to the components. You can do it either inline:

```
<c:ComboBoxMultiSelect skinClass="my.skins.ComboBoxMultiSelectSkin" />
```

or through styling:

```
@namespace c "my.components.*";

c|ComboBoxMultiSelect {
    skinClass: ClassReference("my.skins.ComboBoxMultiSelectSkin")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing that stands out is in your implementation of `updateDisplayList()`. As you know, this is where your component should size and position it's child objects (and/or do any programatic drawing).

But rather than set the child object's width/height directly, you should use one of the Flex lifecycle methods: `setActualSize()` or `setLayoutBoundsSize()`.  Use `setLayoutBoundsSize()` with spark components.

When you set a Flex component's width/height, the component will invalidate itself so that on the next update cycle it can be re-rendered. But since you are trying to render the component in `updateDisplayList()` you should be careful to not invalidate your child objects inside this method.

The `setActualSize()` and `setLayoutBoundsSize()` methods set the width/height on a Flex component, but do not invalidate the component.

```
override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
{
    super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
    _horizontalGroup.setLayoutBoundsSize(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
    // if you wanted to position objects, you would set their x/y coordinates
    // here with the move() or setLayoutBoundsPosition() methods
}
```

Note, it looks like some child objects are being sized in `createChildren()` as well ... and it's not really clear what the base Flex component is in this case (what class does `ReportControl` extend?

Doing it this way **may** get rid of that rendering glitch.  It will most certainly execute less code than if you set width/height properties directly.

**[Edit]**

It may be an interaction with the `HGroup` which is kind of unnecessary in this component. While I think making components this way is fun, it can be more tedious... which is why @RIAStar is wisely pointing out another approach.

Some further ideas, if you want to continue down this path:

1) Take a look at the sizing you are doing in `createChildren()` - for example, the `HGroup` is given a percentWidth, but in `updateDisplayList()` it is given a fixed width (this may be a red herring, but I would not set the percentWidth).

2) You might be able to trick the component into validating itself after you remove it or before you re-add it. A hacky hunch that may be a waste of time.

3) Remove the 'HGroup' from your component. It's kind of unnecessary: the layout requirements are simple enough to do w/a few lines of Actionscript. Your mileage will vary as the layout requirements get more complex!

In `createChildren()` add the combo box and button directly to the `UIComponent`. Then size and position them in `updateDisplayList()`, something like this:

```
override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
{
    super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
    var padding:Number = 10;
    var gap:Number = 0;

    // make the ComboBox consume all of the width execpt for 20px and gap + padding
    var availableWidth:Number = unscaledWidth - 20 - gap - (2*padding);
    _drp.setLayoutBoundsSize(availableWidth, unscaledHeight); // combo box 100% width
    _btnMultiple.setLayoutBoundsSize(20, unscaledHeight); // button is 20px wide

    // now position them ...
    // probably should not use 0, rather calculate a Y coordinate that centers them
    // in the unscaledHeight
    _drp.setLayoutBoundsPosition(padding, 0);
    _btnMultiple.setLayoutBoundsPosition(unscaledWidth - padding - 20, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sunil D, I'll try that out. The `ReportControl` base class extends UIComponent directly. And contains the simplest of simple getters and setters. I'll post the code for it.

Comment: I edited my answer w/some more ideas. However, you might want to consider @RIAStar's wise advice :)

Comment: I saw your post and tried manually positioning the controls instead of the HGroup. I got it displaying correctly but I still see icon problem. I've done some testing and have been able to limit this odd behaviour to just a button with an icon being removed and added back into the display list. I think when a button is added back in, its styles are taking more than one render event to be applied.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both so much for your answers! The consideration and attention to detail in explaining the concepts is awesome! Très bien!

@RIAstar However due to the amount of code already in place, changing my architecture (separating visual element from behavioural) would force to large a re-factor of the code and would cost to much for a feature that hasn't been explicitly requested. (visual representation of the control being able to change at runtime) It certainly is interesting and I will be adding that into a future version.

That said, I think I've been able to find a solution to my problem. I decided to build off of @SunilD.'s suggestion of validating the control before it's added back in. A hack I know, but humans aren't perfect and thus the code aint either. **;-)**

When looking at the control, I noticed it was only the button that was having issues with rendering its image. So to test, I added and removed **JUST** a button instance with an icon, and I saw the same behaviour! (regardless of how comboBoxMultiSelect was implemented) I **ALSO** noticed that I didn't see the button do this when it was first created. So why not just reconstruct the button when it gets removed from the display list?

I ended up wiring `comboBoxMultiSelect` to the `FlexEvent.REMOVE` event, destroy the button reference, create a new one, and add it back in with AddChild(). Below is an explanation of the event.

> "Dispatched when the component is removed from a container as a content
>   child by using the removeChild(), removeChildAt(), removeElement(), or
>   removeElementAt() method. If the component is removed from the
>   container as a noncontent child by using the rawChildren.removeChild()
>   or rawChildren.removeChildAt() method, the event is not dispatched.
>
> This event only dispatched when there are one or more relevant
>   listeners attached to the dispatching object."

Sure enough, this fixed the icon from displaying incorrectly and explains what happening. For some reason the button is taking more than one render event to apply its style when it's added back in. Anyone else able to replicate this behaviour?

I guess the **real question now** is "what is the best way to remove and add-back-in a button to the display list, so that its embedded icon is unaffected?"