# Flex DividedBox children are displayed outside

Tags: apache-flex, children

I am using a DividedBox in Flex which contains only a datagrid at first. When I click on an Item on the Datagrid, a second element with a width of 0% (Spark Group) is added to the divided box to display an image.

The thing is, when the second element is added to the DividedBox, the image is partially displayed outside the DividedBox, and I don't want to have this behavior.

Here is the interesting code :

```
<mx:DividedBox direction="horizontal" id="divider" borderColor="red" borderStyle="solid" borderVisible="true" right="10" left="10" top="10" bottom="10">
    <s:Group width="100%" height="100%">
        <!--datagrid-->
    </s:Group>
</mx:DividedBox>
```

And here is the piece of code that adds the second child of the dividedBox (simplified code) :

```
private var _pdf_preview:Group = new Group();
[Bindable]
[Embed(source="assets/image/llama.jpg")]
private var imgClass:Class;

protected function itemOnClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    _pdf_preview = new Group();
    var img:Image = new Image();
    img.source = imgClass;
    _pdf_preview.addElement(img);
    _pdf_preview.percentWidth = 0;
    divider.addElement(_pdf_preview);
}
```

And here is a screen of the problem (Btw, don't notice my skills on Gimp :) ). As a new user I can't bind images to my post : [screen showing my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2qRH.jpg) the red border show the limits of the dividedBox

Thank you.
I hope there are not too much fault, english is not my native language. Sorry for any english mistakes.

PS : I couldn't add the "DividedBox" tags because it was not existing before, and I'm a "new user" so I can't create new tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `clipContent` property to cut off the image at the edge of the DividedBox:

```
<mx:DividedBox clipContent="true" />
```

When using Spark containers, `clipAndEnableScrolling` is the property you need to achieve the same goal.

I would also like to note that you usually don't require to dynamically add components through ActionScript. You can use 'states' instead. For example:

```
<s:states>
    <s:State name="normal" />
    <s:State name="image" />
</s:states>

<mx:DividedBox clipContent="true">
    <s:DataGrid />
    <s:Image includeIn="image" />
</mx:DividedBox>
```

Now all you need to do to show the Image, is set the `currentState` to `image`.

Comment: Thank you, the clipContent property made the job ! Concerning the fact that I can do that in mxml. Maybe I'm doing it wrong, but I'm not a big fan of the mxml part of Flex, i'd rather do most of the things in ActionScript.

Comment: @pataprout I did share your concern once, but I no longer do. Doing it in AS, is making life hard on yourself. MXML actually does make some things a lot easier. You just have to learn how to nicely separate the MXML view declarations from the ActionScript behavioural code.

Comment: Sometimes it does the job, sometimes not. Especially, I have a lot of problems with event when they are configured in mxml, but I have no problem to add a Listener on them when it is in full AS. I'm sure that the problems that I'm dealing with are totally on my misunderstanding of mxml, but I can't find out how to manage it in MXML.

Comment: @pataprout I totally agree. I hardly ever hook up event listeners in MXML, since there we wander into the realm of behavioural code. I think you should investigate the Spark skinning mechanism. Or you could read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11059302/custom-composite-control-not-rendering-correctly-for-only-0-5-1-sec-after-being/11061988#11061988) I recently wrote, which demonstrates what I mean.